# Failed to load the "Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/wysiwyg" component in admin?

Tags: magento2, page-builder, component

**Magento 2.4.3**

The pagebuilder in admin is not loading at all, I am getting

> Failed to load the "Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/wysiwyg"
> component

as error in the browser console instead. I redeployed, compiled, cleared the cache, nothing worked so far. The Magento_PageBuilder module is enabled. What could be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an answer for this situation?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Magento, which fixed the problem. So, unfortunately, no solution found :(.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue using 2.4.2-p2 , It's strange cause the file actually exists in pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/wysiwyg.js

I have tried many times

```
rm -fr generated/code var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

But issue still present.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by downgrading Pagebuilder. Deleting Magento_PageBuilder files from vendor and running

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder:2.2.0
```